# How to start another Activity using Button inside the Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to open another activity from Fragment Button but every time  I Run the app i will unfortunately Stop.

I've been doing this for a week still can't run the buttons. I will be appreciate if someone gave me answer. I'm new here in android.

My code is about side menu then one of the side menu contains buttons to open a new activity

```
package tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment{


View view;

//Intent i;

public FindPeopleFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ResearchStudy.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            }
            //startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Below is log

```
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843): Process: tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker, PID: 2843
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker/tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker.ResearchStudy}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker.ResearchStudy.onCreate(ResearchStudy.java:12)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Replace `getActivity().startActivity(intent1);` by `startActivity(intent1);` and try again.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Show your logcat.

Comment: still it will unfortunately stop..

Comment: See my answer below @IsaacRoldanMoton

Comment: still giving me

12-31 14:36:33.040: E/AndroidRuntime(2843): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker/tipqc.softeng.sundroidtracker.ResearchStudy}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: I notice when i change the ResearchStudy.class to MainActivity.class .. it is working why researchstudy won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `getActivity().startActivity()` method, with `startActivity()` and it would work!.

Below is the complete code :

```
public FindPeopleFragment(){} 

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), ResearchStudy.class);
                startActivity(intent1);//Edited here
                break; 


            } 
        } 
    }); 

    return view;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write below Line of Code to start Activity from fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public FindPeopleFragment(){} 
 View view;
 @Override 
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{ 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), ResearchStudy.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
            break; 


        } 
    } 
}); 

return view;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

***How to start another Activity using Button inside the Fragment***

This answer mostly suitable for Navigation Drawble in android

**Manifest**

//set path to the new java class which defines under Intent in fragment class

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.mysqlinsert.ui.settings.setLayouts"></activity>
```

**Class which uses Intent in fragment class**

```
public class setLayouts extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.about); 
//layout name which you need to set using onClickListner
    }
}
```

**Fragment Java Class**

`````
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View root =  inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_layoutName, container, false );

        Button about = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.about);

        about.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( getContext(), requiredJavaClassName.class );
                startActivity( intent );
            }

        } );
        return root;
    }
}````
`````